# Is there a way to clone a feature in Drupal/Open Atrium?

Tags: features, distributions

I want to create a clone of the Notebook feature and would like to do it without copying the files and doing a find/replace on the text. Is there an easy/built-in way to clone a feature and provide it with a new name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://drupal.org/project/features_clone.  From the project page:

> Features Clone is a Drush command that allows quick cloning of a Feature. It can be used to rename or fork (e.g. to start a new feature off of an existing one) a Feature installed on a Drupal site.

Comment: Drush/Features Clone doesn't work perfectly, but it does save a tonne of time renaming files and functions. It does a simple find/replace so there are some instances where you need to manually go into the files and replace text...no biggie. Thanks again!